# Hadoop ubuntu client compatibility with centos cluster

Tags: hadoop

can a remote hadoop client with os ubuntu, jdk1.7, and hadoop2.7.1 commununicate with or work on hadoop cluster with Cent Os, Jdk1.8, hadoop2.6.1